Page loading slow even after optimised build
The following page component is at location src/app/posts/[slug].tsx
This is using Next JS 14.
For that api call to http://localhost:5001/posts, I purposely added a 5 seconds delay.
So during npm run dev, it is slow. Fine, as expected.
But then I npm run build it. I get the following for this page.

●  (SSG)     prerendered as static HTML (uses getStaticProps)

So now when I perform npm run start, I am expecting this page to load up instantly.
But it still has the 5 seconds delay. Why? Is my understanding wrong.
P.S: With or without revalidate produces same delayed response.
I have same api call in another page which has:

○  (Static)  prerendered as static content

That loads instantly, ignoring the 5 seconds delay.
Issue only with:

●  (SSG)     prerendered as static HTML (uses getStaticProps)

import Link from 'next/link';

type ArticlePageProps = {
  params: { slug: string };
};

async function getArticles() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5001/posts', { cache: 'no-store' });
  return res.json();
}

async function getArticleByTitle(title: string) {
  const articles = await getArticles();
  return articles.posts.find((article: any) => article.title === title);
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const articles = await getArticles();
  return articles.posts.map((article: { title: string }) => ({
    slug: encodeURIComponent(article.title),
  }));
}

const ArticlePage = async ({ params: { slug }}: ArticlePageProps) => {
  const decodedTitle = decodeURIComponent(slug);
  const article = await getArticleByTitle(decodedTitle);

  if (!article) {
    return <div>Article not found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto py-8">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-6 text-center">Article Details</h1>
      <h2 className="text-xl text-center">{article.title}</h2>
      <p className="font-light text-amber-200 text-center mt-4">{article.summary}</p>
      <div className="mt-8 text-center">
        <Link href="/posts" className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-600">
          Back to Posts
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ArticlePage;

